# Crouton/linux problem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xfce

I've installed Ubuntu on my chrombook using crouton, so I can switch between OS's. However, the screen keeps flickering to chrome OS when I'm using Ubuntu. Does anybody know how this could be fixed? I saw somebody else on the blog who had the same problem so some help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the chroot's xserver, either xorg or xiwi (depending on how you have it set up). If you are using xiwi some flickering is common. If it is truly unbearable you can always reinstall the chroot, or look into using Crostini. Maybe try updating with the core target if it isn't already installed?